# QGIS 1.8 Desktop and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I'm working with Quantum GIS 1.8 Desktop on Ubuntu 11.10. Two days ago the program crashed while I was working with some WMS layers and then it hasn't been working any more. When I open Quantum GIS Desktop the program starts, the logo appears but nothing more happens and then Ubuntu suddenly quit the application.

I have tried several times both to remove Quantum GIS and to reinstall it, but the problem remains.

Could you help me?

Comment: did you try to do $ sudo apt-get purge qgis ? and then re-install?

Comment: re-installing is the quickest and best method. If you used a Virtual Box you can take snapshots - I use this method a lot when testing.

Comment: The first command ($ sudo apt-get purge qgis) doesn't work.

Comment: I have already tried to uninstall and re-install QGIS several times, but this approach doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the dependencies as well. So after

> $sudo apt-get remove qgis

run

> $sudo apt-get autoremove

I hope it works.

Comment: There are two errors:

Comment: Could you please post the errors on your original post?

Comment: I'm haveing some problems with /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: I'm having some problems with /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: You could solve that by deleting the lock file. *rm  /var/lib/dpkg/lock*

Comment: Ubuntu tells me that it's impossible to remove the lock file.

Comment: Oh, forgot to include sudo. *sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*